# jQuery: fill only one of input field and select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I want to make my select menu disabled if a certain input field is filled. On the other hand if any option except none in the select menu is selected then I want that input filed to be disabled. So eventually I want to submit the value of only one input field.

What I did so far:

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/10xcghfj/1/)

jQuery Code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Existing_Client').change(function() {
        if ($("#Existing_Client").val() != "none") {
            $('#New_Client').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
        }
    });

    $('#New_Client').change(function() {
        $('#Existing_Client').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
    });
});
```

Problems in my work:

1. When I select something other than "none", the input filed gets disabled as what I want but when I go again and select none the input field remains disabled!
2. If I typed anything in the input field then select menu won’t be disabled.

Comment: Please show your relevant HTML as well (see the "[MCVE]" guidelines), that way it's easier to provide better answers and useful demonstrations of the proposed answers and solutions therein.

Comment: Why you chose NiZa's answer over mine? No offense, I want to know the reason only.

Comment: @Azim All answers are correct and eventually I have to select only one and NiZa's answer has the least edit to my code :) sorry for that I really appreciate everyone's help ^^

Comment: OK. But it's better to accept best answer. @AsmaaAlharbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Existing_Client').change(function() {   
      $('#New_Client').prop('disabled', $(this).val() === "none" ? false : true); 
  });

  $('#New_Client').on("keyup", function() {
    $('#Existing_Client').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="id" id="Existing_Client">
  <option value="none"></option>
  <option value="Something 1">Something 1</option>
  <option value="Something 2">Something 2</option>
  <option value="Something 3">Something 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="new_id" dir="ltr" id="New_Client" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Existing_Client').change(function() {
        if ($("#Existing_Client").val() != "none") {
            $('#New_Client').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#New_Client').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Existing_Client').change(function() {
      $('#New_Client').prop('disabled', $('option:selected', this).text().length);
  });

  $('#New_Client').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val().length)
    $('#Existing_Client').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length);
  });
});
```

Try this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/10xcghfj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('#Existing_Client').change(function() {
  $('#New_Client').prop('disabled', this.value != "none");
});

$('#New_Client').keyup(function() {
  $('#Existing_Client').prop('disabled', this.value.length != 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="id" id="Existing_Client">
  <option value="none"></option>
  <option value="Something 1">Something 1</option>
  <option value="Something 2">Something 2</option>
  <option value="Something 3">Something 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="new_id" dir="ltr" id="New_Client" />
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/10xcghfj/3/)